# Microsoft AJAX vs jQuery AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

When calling an ASMX service, what benefits (if any) does this:

```
ProjectName.Services.ServiceName.MethodName('methodParameter', function (result) {
    // do something with result
});
```

have over this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: webMethod,
    data: parameters,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {    
        //
    },
    error: function(e){
        //             
    }
});
```

(Please note I'm not interested in "just use WCF, ASMX is outdated", it's purely for AJAX so I'm happy to stick with it for now.)

Comment: Both perform an AJAX request to a `[ScriptMethod]`. What do you mean by *benefits*?

Comment: Well I just read that you can't return a Dictionary using the jQuery way because it's not serializable. Things like that. Not sure what I mean, I'm wondering whether to make the switch to using jQuery instead of MS. I should have probably asked the question "what are the main differences".

Comment: I seriously doubt there's anything the ASMX ajax can do that jQuery can't due to the extensible nature of jQuery.

Comment: The jQuery way will work with non-MS tech so you're future-proofing yourself learning jQuery.ajax.